# Replacing spaces in a string with increasing numbers

Tags: c++

I need a program to take a string and replace spaces with increasing numbers.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Get the String
    string str = "this essay needs each word to be numbered";
    int num = 1;
    string x = num;
    int i = 0;



    // read string character by character.
    for (i < str.length(); ++i) {

        // Changing the loaded character
        // to a number if it's a space.
        if (str[i] == ' ') {

            str[i] = x;
            ++num

        }
    }

    // testing outputs
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << num << endl;

  ofstream file;
  file.open ("numbered.txt");
  file << str;
  file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I had it at the point where it could replace spaces with a letter or symbol and save to a new file but when I tried to make it a number it stopped working. I would need it to say "this1essay2needs3each4word5to6be7numbered

Comment: Not too bad an attempt, but `for (i < str.length(); ++i)` is missing a semi, and `str[i] = x;` tries to assign a whole `string` to a single character, AKA The Bug. You may find tokenizing the string to separate the words and then building in a stringstream to be more useful here. Something like `strm << tokens[num] << ++num;`.

Answer (score 1):

For ease and clarity, change your approach.

- Put the string into an `istringstream`
- Extract each space-separated substring and place into an `std::vector<string>`
- Feed the contents of the vector into a `stringstream` and
- use `std::to_string(num)` to add the numbers between the substrings

e.g.:

```
    std::string str = "this essay needs each word to be numbered";
    int num = 1;

    std::istringstream istr(str);
    std::string temp;
    std::vector<std::string> substrs;
    while (istr >> temp)
    {
      substrs.push_back(temp);
    }
    std::stringstream ostr;
    for (auto&& substr : substrs)
    {
      ostr << substr << std::to_string(num++);
    }
```

Comment: This has a slight change in behaviour, splitting the string on ALL whitespace rather than just on space.

Comment: True. For the problem as described, this solves it, and it has to be modified somewhat for use with `std::cin` anyway.

Comment: To be honest, this is pretty much what I'd do unless space was a hard requirement. There's a case to be made for cutting out the `vector` and writing directly to `ostr`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the problem down into parts. We can make a `SpaceReplacer` object that does the replacement. It has an `Output`, which it can use as a function to output characters:

```
template<class Output>
struct SpaceReplacer {
    Output output; 
    int num_spaces; 
    void input(char c) {
        if(c == ' ') {
             auto num_as_string = std::to_string(num_spaces); 
             num_spaces += 1; 
             for(char digit : num_as_string) {
                 output(digit); 
             }
        }
        else {
            output(c); 
        }
    }
};
```

Every time you input a character, it either outputs the character you input, or it outputs the digits of the number (if the character was a space).

We should write a helper function to make `SpaceReplacer`s:

```
template<class Output>
SpaceReplacer<Output> makeReplacer(Output output_func) {
    return SpaceReplacer<Output>{output_func, 0}; 
}
```

#### Reading one string, returning new string

It's now easy to write a function that replaces spaces in a string.

```
std::string replaceSpaces(std::string const& input) {
    std::string output_string; 
    // We output chars by appending them to the output string
    auto output_func = [&](char c) { output_string += c; }; 
    auto replacer = makeReplacer(output_func); 
    for(char c : input) {
        replacer.input(c); 
    }
    return output_string; 
}
```

#### Reading input from file, replacing spaces and returning a string

Because we wrote a really generic `SpaceReplacer` class, we can modify the function so that it'll read input directly from a `FILE*`

```
std::string replaceSpaces(FILE* file) {
    std::string output_string;
    auto output_func = [&](char c) { output_string += c; }; 
    auto replacer = makeReplacer(output_func); 

    while(true) {
        int input_char = fgetc(file); 
        if(input_char == EOF) {
             break; 
        }
        replacer.input(input_char); 
    }
    return output_string; 
}
```

#### Reading input from one file, immediately appending it to different file with spaces replaced

We can also read directly from one file, and output directly to another file, with no delay. This might be useful if you were processing a very large amount of data.

```
void replaceSpaces(FILE* input_file, FILE* output_file) {
    auto output_func = [=](char c) { fputc(c, output_file); }; 
    auto replacer = makeReplacer(output_func); 

    while(true) {
        int input_char = fgetc(input_file); 
        if(input_char == EOF) {
             break; 
        }
        replacer.input(input_char); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use another string for the result.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Get the String
    string result, str = "this essay needs each word to be numbered qwe qwe  wqe qwe qwe qwe q";
    int num = 0;
    int i;

    // read string character by character.
    for (i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {

        // Changing the loaded character
        // to a number if it's a space.
        if (str[i] == ' ') 
            result+=std::to_string(++num);
        else
            result+=str[i];
    }

    // testing outputs
    cout<<result<<endl;
    cout<<num;

    ofstream file;
    file.open ("numbered.txt");
    file << result;
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to replace it with a character, not by a number.

```
str[i] = num+'0';
```